# Replacing the "if $x ≤ y$, then $x + z ≤ y + z$" axiom in Reals.

Tags: real-analysis, logic, real-numbers, ordered-fields

How can I prove that we cannot (or maybe can) replace preservation of order under addition i.e.  "If $x \leq y$, then  $x + z \leq y + z$  with "if $0<x$ and $0<y$ , then $0<x+y$"
in axioms of the real numbers $(R,+,.,<)$?

Edit: Axiom of the reals:

1. The set $\Bbb{R}$ is a field.
2. The field $\Bbb{R}$ is ordered.

   if $a ≤ b$ then $ a + c ≤ b + c$

   if $0 ≤ a$ and $0 ≤ b$ then $0 ≤ a×b$
3. The order is Dedekind-complete; that is, every non-empty subset S of $\Bbb{R}$ with an upper bound in $\Bbb{R}$ has a least upper bound (also called supremum) in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Could you please list the other axioms you consider as the "axioms of the real line"? The question would be a lot more easier to answer with those.

Comment: @DanulG : 
 
 
axioms of field ; < is total ;the mentioned axiom ; (0<x & 0<y ==> 0<xy)and the D-completeness if you need it

Comment: Have you seen [Tarski's axiomatization of the reals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axiomatization_of_the_reals) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing that axiom would make certain structures into models that were originally not models. For example take standard $\mathbb{R}$ but define every number in the interval $[-10,-5)$ to be greater than every number in the interval $[-5,-4)$. (Additionally we must specify that $[-4,\infty)$ comes after $[-10,-5)$ and $(-\infty, -10)$ comes before $[-5,4)$... essentially we can muck about with the order of any entirely negative half closed intervals).

We see that $<$ is still asymmetric, dense, and D-complete. Addition is unchanged. The statement that "$x \le y \rightarrow x + z \le y + z$" is false: example $-7 \le -6$ but $-7 + 1 \ge -6 + 1$, but the new axiom is still true.

Comment: what is the supremum of [-5,-4)? -4 or -10?

Comment: The supremum would be -10.

Comment: -6<-5 & -4.5<-5 ===>(totality) -4.5<-5; Doesn't [-10,-5) mean -10<=x<-5?

Comment: I suppose some convenience notations would require some tweaking... The primary point is the consequence of the axiom change allows one to change the less than relation without changing the addition operation. Such a model is rather useless, but it is technically a model.